# Quickfixn Message Logging in Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, quickfix, quickfixn

I am using the Quickfixn library, I have succeeded in editing my dictionary and generating new classes, but at the moment I am looking into how to use the database for my logging, messages, etc.

I have seen that the C++ version and possibly the java version do support the feature and was wondering if I could do the same  with Quickfixn.

Answer (score 3):

Those features are not written at this time.  (Note: I am the project's maintainer.)

If you wanted to take a stab at it, you would need to write implementations of `ILogFactory` and `IMessageStoreFactory`.

Comment: IStorefactory does not exist, is it rather IMessageSToreFactory?

Comment: I have managed to sort out the logging to go to the database, my question is how do I manage sessions? As i keep getting a new session every time I start a session, this is resetting my session sequence number all the time.